# How to retrieve Membership's PasswordAnswer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

It is encypted in the table. I don't want to reset the password.
I got a solution at [here](http://throughexperience.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-retrieve-memberships.html)

But I am not sure the namespace of

> base.DecryptPassword

Because I got an error, can not find it.

Updated again:

```
updated my code:

public class FalseMembershipProvider: MembershipProvider
{
    public string GetPasswordAnswer(Guid providerUserKey)
    {
        Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        using (System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT PasswordAnswer FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID=@UserID"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@UserId", DbType.Guid, providerUserKey);
            object answer = db.ExecuteScalar(cmd); if (answer != null)
                return ProviderDecryptor(answer.ToString());
            else
                return null;
        }
        db = null;
    }
    internal string ProviderDecryptor(string encryptedText)
    {
        string decrypted = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedText))
        {
            byte[] encodedbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            byte[] decryptedbytes = base.DecryptPassword(encodedbytes);
            if (decryptedbytes != null)
                decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedbytes, 16, decryptedbytes.Length - 16);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is inheriting from the `MembershipProvider` class. The method being called is [MembershipProvider.DecryptPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword.aspx). However, as you can see on the MSDN page, it's a `protected` method. By inherting from `MembershipProvider`, this new class can use `base.DecryptPassword` which is essentially saying "call the DecryptPassword method of the MembershipProvider. Even though the method is protected, I can call it because I have permission since I'm inheriting from the MembershipProvider class".

The class you're writing needs to inherit from `MembershipProvider` as the author did in their example:

```
public class FalseMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
```

Comment: How to add it because I already inhert something? Example:      public partial class EditInfo : System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: You can just create a new class and call it from your page. It doesn't have to be added on to your current class.

Comment: Got a bunch of errors. Such as "FalseMembershipProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.FindUsersByEmail(string, int, int, out int)' etc.

Comment: You have to implement the other mandatory methods. Right click on the MembershipProvider and click `Implement Abstract Class`. You can fill out the ones you need. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx. Why do you want to implement a custom provider to recover the password? If you just want to retreive the password, can't you just use the PasswordRecovery control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: No, I am not doing recovering the password. What I meant is to find passwordanswer. Ex, Question: What is your faviour color? Answer: red. The answer is hashed in the table. The PasswordAnswer is not password itself. The errors are still there even I right click "Implement Abstract Class".

Comment: When you selected `Implement Abstract Class`, did all the methods appear with `NotImplementedExceptions`? I just created a new class, right-clicked and no errors were thrown.

Comment: I rebuild the solution and the errors only have two. Thanks.  MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
 FalseMembershipProvider falseMembershipProvider = new FalseMembershipProvider();
                TextSecurityAnswer.Text = falseMembershipProvider.GetPasswordAnswer(user.ProviderUserKey);

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Guid'

Comment: Use `MembershipProvider.GetPasswordAnswer((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);`